# How to filter/exclude inactive comments from my annotated Django query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-managers, generic-relationship

I'm using the `object_list` generic view to quickly list a set of Articles.  Each Article has comments attached to it.  The query uses an annotation to `Count()` the number of comments and then `order_by()` that annotated number.

```
'queryset': Article.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).order_by('-comment_count'),
```

The comments are part of the `django.contrib.comments` framework and are attached to the model via a Generic Relationship.  I've added an explicit reverse lookup to my Article model:

```
class Article(models.Models):
   ...
   comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk')
```

The problem is, this counts "inactive" comments; ones that have `is_public=False` or `is_removed=True`.  How can I exclude any inactive comments from being counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for aggregations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) explains how to do this. You need to use a `filter` clause, making sure you put it *after* the `annotate` clause:

```
Article.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments')).filter(
     comment__is_public=True, comment__is_removed=False
).order_by('-comment_count')
```

Comment: wouldn't that filter articles based on whether or not they have public/removed comments?

Comment: It seems to have worked but I'm going to do some investigating to make sure what Jim said isn't happening.

Comment: One side effect I did notice is that it ONLY returns articles that have comments, those without are excluded.